# How to find only headwords (entries of a foreign language dictionary) using text search in PDF Reader?

Tags: hyperref, indexing

I'm working on a two language dictionary (german-french) with some thousand entries (headwords). Each entry has the following structure:

```
\hypertarget{headword}{}
\index{headword}
{\de{german}}{\fr{french}}
cf. \hyperlink{link_1}{hword_1} / 
    \hyperlink{link_2}{hword_2} / … / 
    \hyperlink{link_n}{hword_n}
[more examples etc. concerning <headword>...
 see picture below: headword "Probe"]
```

with `link_i` pointing to another headword in the dictionary.

Now, using full text search in the resulting PDF for passages containing headword, I get **every instance** of headword in the file.

How can it be achieved to find **only the entry** headword (e.g. "Probe" below) using  text search in a PDF file?

[image: PDF output, headword with infos]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

TEXT, with some instances of 
Experiment, Probe % these instances should NOT be found by textsearch in PDF

%--- HEADWORD "Experiment", this should be found by textsearch in PDF
\hypertarget{Experiment}{}
\index{Experiment}
\begin{tabular}{p{60mm}p{60mm}}
das Experiment, e & l’expérience, expérimentation \\
cf.  die \hyperlink{Probe}{Probe} 
\end{tabular}

\newpage

TEXT ...

%--- HEADWORD "Probe", this should be found by textsearch in PDF 
\hypertarget{Probe}{}
\index{Probe}
\begin{tabular}{p{60mm}p{60mm}}
die Probe, n &  l’entraînement, la répétiton  \\
cf.  das \hyperlink{Experiment}{Experiment} 
\end{tabular}

TEXT ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this case, some entries would suffice

Comment: I would also use a new separate command for your entries,so that you can keep your file simple and clean.

Comment: The usage of `\hypertarget` is wrong, see https://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/ftp/doc/manual.html#x1-140004. You always add the symbolic name **headword** but do not provide the text which is to be achieved with this **headword**. There should be a lot of warnings about that? Each entry should have a separate headword-entry, e.g. build from something like a counter value etc.

Comment: Well, your screen shot shows how the document looks like (or should look), but there is no code to work with. Please provide a MWE.

Comment: Unfortunately (because I think it's an interesting question) this is rather off-topic: The solution is bound to be specific to your pdf reader (unless you break every word in your pdf output at every letter with a zero-width space, or some such nonsense).  This is unlikely to be a feature popular with users of general-purpose pdf-reading software, so unlikely to be implemented (I don't know if you follow what ebook-publishers get up to in terms of restricting their users, but they'd find some way to be annoying with it).

Comment: @Chris: If my question is really off-topic, where should I ask my question?

Comment: @WolfgangBüchel, I wish I knew of somewhere.  I would keep it here for now given how knowledgeable some people here are -- some at least seem to relish a puzzle.  If you have a particular reader in mind you may be able to get some help at for example superuser, but if the solution has to be generated in TeX you're better off here.  Partly I was expecting that your question might end up being closed as off-topic, and partly trying to shed a different light on the problem.

Comment: @WolfgangBüchel: After thinking about your problem, your request would mean that your document is not searchable, except from the hyperlinked words/entries. I fear, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PDF viewer dependent solution

I have been using [`accsupp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) for this purpose. The presented solution works in [Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/), 
Document Viewer ([Evince](http://sourceforge.net/projects/evince.mirror/)), [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) and [Xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/), but it doesn't work in [FoxIt Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/) and [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\def\hideme#1{%
  \BeginAccSupp{unicode,ActualText={}}%
    #1%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
  }
\hideme{Experiment}\par
\hideme{Experiment} to hide.\par
Term\par
\hideme{Term} to hide.\par
TEXT, with some instances of 
\hideme{Experiment}, \hideme{Probe}% 
% these instances should NOT be found by textsearch in PDF
\bigskip\par

%--- HEADWORD "Experiment", this should be found by textsearch in PDF
\hypertarget{Experiment}{}
\index{Experiment}
\begin{tabular}{p{60mm}p{60mm}}
das Experiment, e & l’expérience, expérimentation \\
cf.  die \hyperlink{Probe}{\hideme{Probe}} 
\end{tabular}

%\newpage
\bigskip
TEXT ...

%--- HEADWORD "Probe", this should be found by textsearch in PDF 
\hypertarget{Probe}{}
\index{Probe}
\begin{tabular}{p{60mm}p{60mm}}
die Probe, n &  l’entraînement, la répétiton  \\
cf.  das \hyperlink{Experiment}{\hideme{Experiment}}
\end{tabular}

TEXT ...
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Great, that works indeed.

Comment: But now ONLY the headwords can be searched for (I asked for that, I know). That is quite a big restriction (as Chris already wrote). - 
So: Is there a way to search for the  headwords with an extra character (e.g. Probe#) and for the other instances with their regular, unmarked form (e.g. Probe, without #)?

Comment: In this example you can control the output of a wrapped part (`#1`) and a searchable part (`ActualText={...}`). As I understand it you would like to wrap the headwords and set `ActualText={#1\#}`, please try it.

Comment: `ActualText={#1\#}` did'nt not work for me, but `ActualText={#1+}` did it. This solution affords marking **only** the headwords, not **all** words to be excluded from searching. And so all words can still be searched. - Thank you for your proposal.